# jQuery: добавление стилей на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Я подключаю стили к своему веб-приложению с помощью js. В head у меня содержится нечто подобное:

```js
<script src="/template/default/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function includeCssFile($path) {
    if (Array.isArray($path)) 
       for (i = 0; i < $path.length; i++) 
          $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + $path[i] + "'>");
  }

</script>
```

Стили подключаются, все ок, но проблема в том, что при загрузке страницы (если .css файла нету в кэше!) на долю секунды страница отображаться без css. Я так понимаю в это время именно загружается сам файл. Подскажите, как можно исправить ситуацию, а именно дождаться загрузки css и только после этого отображать страницу.

Comment: Реализуйте подключение стилей через `php`

Comment: Или используйте прелоадер

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае можно использовать прелоадер, для примера взял с этого [сайта](https://hello-site.ru/preloader/):

```js
var hellopreloader = document.getElementById("hellopreloader_preload");

function fadeOutnojquery(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 1;
  var interhellopreloader = setInterval(function() {
    el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - 0.05;
    if (el.style.opacity <= 0.05) {
      clearInterval(interhellopreloader);
      hellopreloader.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, 16);
}
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fadeOutnojquery(hellopreloader);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#hellopreloader>p {
  display: none;
}

#hellopreloader_preload {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  background: #E4F1FE url(http://hello-site.ru//main/images/preloads/oval.svg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 114px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hellopreloader">
  <div id="hellopreloader_preload"></div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```